# Why setStyle does not work for point geometry from cluster?

Tags: openlayers

I use this code to chnage style (just color icon) of point element from cluster:

```
if (ft.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point') {
      ft.setStyle(
        new Style({
          image: new Icon({
            color: '#000000',
            src: `${this.baseHref}${pointIcon.src}`,
          }),
        })
      );
    }
```

The `ft` is:

[image]

Comment: Please put you entire question in the body of the question, not only in title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cluster features are regenerated every time the view changes, any setting you make will be lost when that happens, so you should always use a style function on the layer to style them.

You can make changes to features within a cluster (but it must not cause change events)

```
clusterFeatuure.get('features').forEach(function(feature) {
  // do something with feature
})
```

For example set the color of the cluster depending on whether all, some or none of the features in it were in a cluster which was clicked earlier https://codesandbox.io/s/cluster-forked-ukrcjc?file=/main.js

Comment: How to change the point in cluster by hover? I use IMAGE: ICON

Comment: Easiest way would to to use a select interaction, and set an alternative style on that https://codesandbox.io/s/cluster-forked-jbsd84?file=/main.js